# How to update filter in graphql query string body?

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing, graphql, filtering

I have a rest API that is a proxy to graphql API. Before I send the query to the actual graphql API, I need to update the filter object.

```
test_query = { "query": "{ \
    viewer { \
        socks(filter: {sockId:'12345'}) { \
            colorGroups( \
                limit: 10000, \
                filter: { \
                    datetime_gt: '2019-02-13T00:00:00Z', \
                    datetime_lt: '2019-02-20T00:00:00Z'}, \
                orderBy: [datetime_ASC]) { \
                    size, \
                    brand \
                } \
        } \
    } \
}"}
```

In this case, I need to update the filter on the 'socks' node as such:

`socks(filter: {sockId:'12345'})`
needs to be
`socks(filter: {sockId:'actual sock id'})`

Any advice for this? I know there are a few graphql libraries I  could use.  Previously I tried to force user to send `{sockId: $sockId}` and just added the correct value to variables object. I have also tried using regexes to sub the value user send for sockId but that has proved to be sort of limiting.

Comment: variables should be used

Answer (score 0):

It's a JSON what you have (you could use JSON.parse), but I'd create a query object, modify it and then use JSON.stringify(object).

Also if you want to stick with strings, use string interpolation and variables: str = `here '${war}' i do have the value of the variable war`.